# Implement logic app and function app in the same repository

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am try to implement logic app and function app in the same repository, but some how I can not start logic app locally. Below is my structrure, I seperate 2 folder, one for /logic-app and one for /src. Does anyone know how to implement it.

[image]

I have no idea how to implement it in the same repos.

Answer (score 0):

> Implement logic app and function app in the same repository

Creating Logic apps and Functions in same folder is not recommended because both of them have files with same name, so its been confusing at your end.

It worked for me when I created Folder structure like below:

```
MAIN
├── Lozicapp
│   ├── workflow.json        
│   └── ...                   
├── Functions
│   ├── function-code         
│   └── ...
└── README
```

[image]

Then inside the Functions create functions and inside logic app folder create logic app flows like below and it will work as mine got worked:

[image]

[image]